# Jenkins conditionalstep groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, conditional-statements, dsl

I tried to use this Conditional multi step plugin and wrote the grrovy script for DSL however when i bootstrap using this code, the steps listed are outside before the conditional block, what am i doing wrong here?

Ref: https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.conditionalSteps

Code:

```
def configSeed(environment, slaveLabel) {
   { it ->
      parameters {
        stringParam('BUILD_REQUIRED', 'true', '');
    }
    scm {
        git {
            remote {
                name('origin');
                url('xyz');
                refspec('$GERRIT_REFSPEC');
                credentials('xyz');
            }
            branch('$GERRIT_BRANCH');
            strategy {
                gerritTrigger();
            }
        }
    }
    steps {
        conditionalSteps {
            condition {
                stringsMatch('${BUILD_REQUIRED}', 'true', false)
            }
            runner('Fail')
            steps {
                environmentVariables {
                    envs(environment);
                }
                batchFile('''
                    call npm install
                    ''');                   
                batchFile('''
                    call mkdir buildArchive
                    ''');
            }
        }
    }
    publishers {
        wsCleanup {
            includePattern('build/**')
        }
    }
    wrappers {
        preBuildCleanup();
        timeout {
            noActivity(300);
            abortBuild();
        }
    }
    label(slaveLabel);
 }
};
```

So jenkins job which gets created is shown as

```
npm install
mkdir buildArchive

Conditional step
```

Instead of

```
Conditional step
{
   npm install
   mkdir buildArchive
}
```

What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: what does _"... the steps listed are outside before the conditional block..."_ mean?

Comment: @tim_yates updated the description above. I see the commands outside above conditional step instead of within it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you generate a job with your steps configuration

```groovy
job('foobar') {
    steps {
        conditionalSteps {
            condition {
                stringsMatch('${BUILD_REQUIRED}', 'true', false)
            }
            runner('Fail')
            steps {
                environmentVariables {
                    envs(FOO: 'bar', TEST: '123')
                }
                batchFile('call npm install')               
                batchFile('call mkdir buildArchive')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the result seems fine:

[image]

In my experience, when you have any issues with the Job DSL syntax and its results, a good approach is to diff the config.xml of your job:

- Manually configure your job, as you want it to be, and save the config.xml
- Generate your job locally and save the config.xml as well
- Diff the two configuration files and look out for the exact XML tag order
- Then trial and error to see what is going on when you change the Job DSL script

When I started to use the Job DSL with no experience with groovy - especially closures ;) - I had a lot of simmilar issues when I tried to extract job configuration blocks into methods like in your case. This is what helped me to understand what is really going on.